# with-accessors for all accessors?

Tags: elisp-macros

common lisp has a [`with-accessors`](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/object-reorientation-classes.html) macro which is pretty useful but it is still prone to lots of code duplication.

Is there a convenient let/binding macro that makes all accessors from a `defclass` available as variables without having to name them all in advance? It would require a magical lookup of the class accessor definition at macro expansion time and I'm not sure if that's possible.

Comment: Do you mean Emacs-Lisp `defclass`, which is in eieio? Or do you mean Common-Lisp `defclass` (which I don't think Emacs Lisp has an emulation of - no `cl-defclass`)?

Comment: Actually EIEIO's `defclass` is pretty close to Common-Lisp's.

Comment: @fommil: as you guessed, while it could arguably be possible in some cases, it's basically impossible in general to do that at macroexpansion time.  OTOH we could provide something like that if you provide the name of the class/struct.

Comment: If the macro just took an extra parameter, the name of the class,  I'd be delighted! Would need the support the accessors of parent classes too. This could allow us to basically rewrite ensime in much less code.